# Syntax error or access violation in Laravel and MySql

Tags: laravel

**I have the following code in Laravel**

```
$total_for_indicators_per_date = Ed_data_count::where('ed_indicator_id', $indicator_id)
->orderby('date', 'asc')
->selectRaw("sum(count_c) as sum_x,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b-%y') date_x")
->groupBy('date')->get();
```

**When trying this code on the server, I get the following error.**

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column

I know that we can overcome this issue by making strict option disabled in the configuration files, but this solution is very dangerous from a security viewpoint.

I have tried to set the strict option for only the request, using the following code, but it seems nothing has solved

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.strict', false);
$total_for_indicators_per_date = Ed_data_count::where('ed_indicator_id', $indicator_id)
->orderby('date', 'asc')
->selectRaw("sum(count_c) as sum_x,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b-%y') date_x")
->groupBy('date')->get();
```

It seems that the query running using enabled strict, although I set it as false.

The question is where the issue in the last technique, which I have used.

PS : I don't prefer to make "order by" after "group by".

Comment: With mysql full group by mode, all non-aggregate select columns and order by columns must be named in group by clause. Alternatively you can look to employ sub queries to achieve what you want

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The code work perfect in localhost, the issue occur in the server, No problem in the query, I need solution without changing the query, I have a lot of code, no way to change all codes.

Comment: That means that the MySQL server you have locally does not have  `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode enabled.

Comment: Do you mean that enabling this attribute in server will solve the issue?